# Debugging jest unit tests with create-react-app doesn't hit breakpoint in VSCode

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs, create-react-app

I was trying to debug tests created with create-react-app/jest/enzyme and can't hit breakpoint in VScode. When I run debug "Debug CRA Tests" everything kind of working and test passes but it doesn't hit breakpoint in VSCode.

Have I missed anything in my config/setup ?

```
import React from "react";
import { configure, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import Input from "./Input";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("<Input />", () => {

    it("should render <Input label=.../> with label", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Input elementType="input" />);
        wrapper.setProps({ label: "test" });
        expect(wrapper.find("label")).toHaveLength(1);
    });

});
```

and there is my launch.json:

```
   {
        "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
        "args": [
            "test",
            "--runInBand",
            "--no-cache"
        ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
    }
```

and my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.6",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.4.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "^16.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5",
    "react-swipeable": "^4.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.4"
  }

....
```

Comment: I think it's an ongoing issue; check [#5846](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5846).

Comment: Try running tests just in the file you want to debug. In watch mode, it is "p", then file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue while using the vscode launch configuration indicated in create-react-apps docs.

It didn't work because the `--no-watch` argument is not working. **The solution**: using another way they have to not use the watch mode:

```
"env": {
    "CI": "true"
}
```

The full configuration working (Node v8.12.0, react-scripts v2.1.3, Jest 23.6.0)

```
 {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
      "args": ["test", "--runInBand", "--no-cache", "--no-watch"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "env": {
        "CI": "true"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

which is the one stated in their documentation at the time of writing